# What is the reason behind this formula: 2 times interquartile range divided by length to the power of one third

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

In `ggplot2` package documentation for `geom_freqpoly`, there is a formula in the last example which use a function to dynamically calculate a bandwidth in histograms of different variables with different ranges. Does anyone know the intuition behind this formula (last line of code following the `functionx(x)`)?

Copy and pasted from the documentation:

```
# You can specify a function for calculating binwidth, which is
# particularly useful when faceting along variables with
# different ranges because the function will be called once per facet

ggplot(economics_long, aes(value)) +
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales = 'free_x') +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = function(x) 2 * IQR(x) / (length(x)^(1/3)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedman%E2%80%93Diaconis_rule) is the [Freedman-Diaconis rule](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.650.2473&rep=rep1&type=pdf) to calculate the *width* of bins for a histogram.

[IQR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_range) stands for Interquartile Range (apologies if you already know this, someone else may be seeing it here for the first time), which is the difference between the 3rd and 1st quartiles of the data distribution, also referred to as the middle 50% of data. `2*IQR` is an attempt to get the spread of most of the data.  Dividing by the cubed root of the number of samples in the data leads to a statistical justification for choosing binwidth, rather than empirically guessing. In the paper, they provide a justification for `length(x)^(1/3)` based on observations and a mathematical proof. It basically improves the binwidth for large data samples.